# how to manipulate child control in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

I am trying to manipulate (move up and down, enable/disable and launch a form) child controls inside a panel control. However I am unable to get the id of the child control on which the click event occurs.

To illustrate, I am trying to create similar functionality as is available. I am trying to create the up-down buttons that you see in the image at http://i34.tinypic.com/2gugio6.jpg

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unable to get the id of the child control on which the click event occurs.

Use `event.currentTarget` inside the event handler to access the child control in which the event occurred.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you post some code. Since I don't know the details, I am giving you the most basic answer.

For example, if you want id of a button in your code, you specify that id in the mxml. So,

```
<mx:Button label="myButton" id="btn1"/>
```

Now, say in your script you want to add an event listener here, you access this as

```
btn1.addEventListener ....
```

Now, lets say you want to access not a button or some independent control, but you want to access elements inside a list, there are several ways. I am presuming you would like to access the selected item. You simply say

```
list1.selectedItem
```

As I said, it would help if you post your code and specify a more precise problem.